# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{n^2\sin{(nx)}}{1+n^2x}$ on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to first check if $(f_n)$ is pointwise convergent here but I seem to be having an issue with that much.

I was trying to split this into $x$ either being a multiple of $\pi$ or not. But there will be some $n$ where $\sin{(nx)}$ is no longer zero, so now I'm not sure where to go with this.

This stuff seems very discouraging when I'm trying to learn it.

edit:I'm sorry guys, just realized I had been saying continuous, but I'm actually looking at uniform convergence here.

Comment: Note that if you want uniform continuity of $f_n$, this means that $n$ is fixed. This has nothing to do with the sequence.

Comment: Okay, so was I correct in trying to split this into cases to first find if $f_n$ is pointwise continuous?

Comment: Prove directly that $f_n$ is uniformly continuous. The fact that it is continuous does not help, since the domain is not compact. And you should not say pointwise continuous. Continuous is enough.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware of that since in class we've typically started our problems by showing $f_n$ is continuous. I'll just go straight to showing it is uniformly continuous then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** the question has been changed.

The sequence $f_n(x)$ converges if and only if $x\in \pi \mathbb{N}^*$, in which case it converges to $0$.

Observe that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{n^2}{1+n^2x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n^2}+x}=\frac{1}{x}\neq 0
$$
but 
$$
\sin(nx)
$$
does not converge in general.

Indeed, if $\frac{x}{\pi}$ is irrational, $x\mathbb{N}-\pi \mathbb{N}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and every point of $[-1,1]$ is the limit of some subsequence of $\sin (nx)$.

Now assume $\frac{x}{\pi}=\frac{p}{q}$ is rational with $p,q$ relatively prime.

If $q=1$, the sequence is constant equal to $0$, so it converges to $0$.

If $q>1$, then the sequence $\sin (nx)$ is $q$ periodic and takes distinct values, so it does not converge.

Comment: If this is true then the sequence $(sin(nx))$ is uniform convergent on $(0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean pointwise continuity? Both the numerator and denominator look continuous to me, and on the range specified the denominator is never 0.

Comment: Well I wanted to first determine pointwise continuity so I could go on to determine if it is uniformly continuous or not. I'm just having issues doing this.